# How to debug joomla behaviors?

Tags: debug, header

I was using protostar for a looong time. I jsut bought a theme and switched to it (it uses helix framework).

As soon as i switched it. On all pages a text appeared 
"// You can place JavaScript like..." />" First line after body tag.

I though it was the sourcerer first i disabled it but nothing changed. I installed the theme to a fresh joomla install and vala no text there. But i am developing this site for long time. I dont know which  extension is causing it. Weird thing is that it is not there if i use protostar.

No tags around, first text. I searched file contents and it didn't worked.

I can not see when it is loaded, i can not see which file outputs it.
How can i debug something like this ?

Comment: Have you checked all the template settings? Many templates provide a text area to insert javascript.

Comment: @james Yes. Helix is clean, it has custom code settings all of them are empty text areas. I couldn't find anything like that in protostar.

Comment: 1. does it appear on non com_content pages, eg. a login page.?
2. does it appear if you load a page with &tmpl=component on the end of the url?
3. do you have a system plugin like jquery easy or something running?

Comment: @jamesgarrett i get it on login pages too. I do not get it on 404 not found page. I have jce editor and sourcerer plug-in which i suspected asap however when i disable it nothing changes.

Comment: @james sourcerer plug in writes "// You can place JavaScript like this" (ON PAGES) . But what i see at the top of the page right after body tag is  "// You can place JavaScript like..." />" what the hell is this. I downloaded all the files and searched the contents in it. no luck . i found the sourcerer buyt its written "this" isntead of "..." i changed the text. top text is same.

Comment: @jamesgarrett I might have added some copy paste code to quick fix smt way back. however i updated joomla version recently. And how can it disappear at protostar. And how none of the files contain this text. If for some reason the sourcerer text copied to a mysterious location and cut by the system and replaced with "..." maybe

Comment: put ?tmpl=component on the end of any URL.  This will load the component.php template of your template rather than the index.php
If the text appears straight after the body tag then it must be either in the template, or is being loaded by a system plugin, and if the text is no where in any file then it's probably loaded as a param by a plugin and you might be able to find it like this: 
SELECT * FROM `#__extensions` WHERE `params` LIKE '%place JavaScript like%'

Comment: If your server is linux and you have access to the command line, try searching for files containing "You can place JavaScript like" with a command like `grep -r "You can place JavaScript like" "/joomlaroot"` You would need to substitute your actual joomla root directory for /joomlaroot (for example `/usr/share/nginx/html` or `/var/www/html` or other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a sourcerer tag used in the facebook og tag generator.  If you switch the view source you can see it like this:

```
    <meta property="og:description" content=" <!-- You can place html anywhere within the source tags --> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> // You can place JavaScript like..." />

</head>
```

The content you can see in the body is just spilling out the broken tag.  I don't know whether the og tag is generated by the template or a plugin.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, it was theme in theme files. calling additional functions which outputs that broken tag.